# regex for repeating patterns

Tags: regex, logging, fail2ban

i have a dovecot logfile which contains entrys like this:

`Jun  1 04:16:24 mail dovecot: auth-worker(3158): sql(ryan,193.42.32.170): unknown user (given password: ryan)`

i want to create a fail2ban filter that blocks any login attempts where username is same as given password, so far i have:

`failregex = auth-worker.*,<HOST>,.* (Password mismatch|unknown user) .*given password: ryan.*`

this only works fo this specific password, but i want it to work with any combination of username/password is the same to block dictionary attacks

The current regex is working, but its very limited in a usecase

Comment: Where is the username part, you can try using capturing group, example: https://regex101.com/r/6TAbc4/1

Comment: NB: your example entry has only one comma, yet your regex looks for two commas... I don't see how it could match.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the user in a named capturing group with
[this syntax](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) :

`(?P<group_name> ... )` where `...` is your pattern.

Then, you can re-use this captured content in the rest of the pattern, by
using a named backreference like this :

`(?P=group_name)`

So for your example, I presume the user is next to the IP address, in bold here :

*Jun  1 04:16:24 mail dovecot: auth-worker(3158): sql(**ryan**,193.42.32.170): unknown user (given password: ryan)*

If this is the case, then you can use this regular expression :

```
auth-worker.*?sql\((?P<user>\w+),(?P<ip>\d+(?:\.\d+){3}).*?(?:password mismatch|unknown user)\s*\(given password:\s*(?P=user)\)
```

I don't know how you enable the case-**i**nsensitive flag in fail2ban, but
I was a bit surprised with the capital "P" on "Password mismatch". You might
have to play around with this:

https://regex101.com/r/pTXjmM/1

Also check that the username pattern is valid. Here I just used `\w+` but
maybe your users can use other characters. And if you have IPv6, you'll have
to adapt the capturing *ip* group, as I presume that you need it to ban it.

Answer (score 0):

Fail2ban has own regex for detecting ipv4 or ipv6, so  is doing it's job here already

i tinkered a little bit with it and indeed got it to work testing with fail2ban-regex

But i did another approach, i gave chatgpt a try, provided the question:

```
create a regular expression from the following log entry, that detects if a given username matches the same password:

Jun  1 02:47:50 mail dovecot: auth-worker(2587): sql(holly,193.42.32.97): unknown user (given password: holly)
```

to my very surprise, chatgpt gave me this:

```
^(.*?) dovecot: auth-worker\(\d+\): sql\((\w+),.*?\): unknown user \(given password: \2\)$
```

i tinkered a lil more with it and in the end, this is the final result:

```
auth-worker.*(.*?).*(\w+),<HOST>.*?\).*(Password mismatch|unknown user).*given password: \2\)
```